# iCloud and Core Data - How to debug?

Tags: ios, debugging, core-data, icloud

I have an Library-style app which uses Core Data to store its data. Currently I am working on the integration of iCloud support.

I worked through several examples and the Apple docs and finally managed that an object created on device A is automatically synced to device B.

That is great but know I am experiencing the some problems: Some objects are synced and others are not and I have no idea how to debug this. Is there some way to "see" which data is transfered to iCloud, which data is stored in the cloud, and which data is downloaded from iCloud?

All I see at the moment is, that I create some NSManagedObject and store it to the ManagedContext/PersistentStore. I cannot see if it is transfered to the cloud and I cannot see the current content of the cloud. This makes it unpossible to debug the whole process.

So how to debug iCloud?

**EDIT on 06/02/2015**
I asked this question quite a while ago but it still gets some up votes or favorites. Therefore I would like to share some information I got meanwhile:

DO NOT USE iClOUD! I cannot tell you how many headacdhes and sleepless nights I had because of iCloud. It is jut not worth the candles. At least not when being used with Core Data. It just does not work reliably. This is even still true with iCloud Drive. My apps "supported" iCloud for about two years I did everything possible to get it running. Every time it seems to work I got new error messages from users. It worked fine for many users and caused trouble and even crashes for many othes. It was just terrible. Do your self a favour and use any other syncing service.

Comment: Which syncing service do you recommend? My app needs to support both USA and China, thus Parse.com and Dropbox are not feasible... yet I'm not sure if making my own server makes sense. Also, do you use some syncing framework or wrote your own? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that there is one best solution for every project. It simply depends on your requirements. In my case Dropbox was the right solution.

Comment: Thanks! Did you write your own syncing mechanism from scratch?

Comment: I switched away from using CoreData to a SQLite solution. This might not be a good idea in any situation but when developing for different platforms it was the right way for me. Dropbox is then used as shared folder across different devices. Each device checks if theres is a copy of the database available in Dropbox. This copy is than downloaded and synced against the local database. The result is than uploaded back to the Dropbox where the next device can find it. This solution will actually work with any online storage and is not limited to Dropbox.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the details! Yes I can see it only works for small data storage since every time you replace the whole database :)

Comment: This is correct. However the app database is quite small, even with selveral thousand entries only 2-3 MB. Transferring a zipped version reduces this to a few hundred KB. Of course still more than just transferring changes logs like iCloud but it works reliable (other than iCloud) Another solution I used was a WebService: The App translated all changed table rows since last sync data to JSON strings and transfered them the service. The service synced this information to its own database and send back the sync result to the app. Less payload but harder to implement.

Comment: My app is note and images centric, thus I'm thinking of a file based syncing system, since I don't want to re-sync images when unnecessary. It'd be more complicated than whole database replacement, but not as complicated as transaction logs which drove iCloud insane... JSON probably is the right approach for text & attributes, I'll see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tried the [mitmproxy](http://mitmproxy.org/) to see what is send and what is received?

There is a GameCenter tutorial at http://mitmproxy.org/doc/tutorials/gamecenter.html , it should be similar for iClound transfers.

Comment: Thank you for that hint. The tools looks promising! This might help to see the communication between the devices and iCloud and to find problems with the communication. But what about if the data seems to be transfered to iCloud correctly but another device does not get any message about that new data? Is there any way to see what is actually in the cloud? I fear the answer is no but I am not sure of that.

Comment: Don't know myself about tracing inside iCloud. I, too, assume the answer is no

Answer (score 6):

There seems to be a runtime argument

```
-com.apple.coredata.ubiquity.logLevel 3
```

check this article http://www.freelancemadscience.com/fmslabs_blog/2012/3/28/debug-settings-for-core-data-and-icloud.html?